# JavaScript settings constructor in subclass?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

Below is a simple JavaScript inheritance example. What is the purpose for the line
from below?

**Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;**

It seem if I un-comment or comment-out, the code give me the same output.

```
function Animal(age){
    this.age = age;
    console.log("Animal constructor called")
}
Animal.prototype.walk = function(){
     console.log("Animal with age " + this.age + " walked"); 
}

function Dog(color, age){
    this.color = color;
    Animal.call(this, age)
    console.log("Dog constructor called")
}

Dog.prototype = new Animal();      
//Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;

dog = new Dog("white", 10);
console.log("Age: " + dog.age +  " Color: " + dog.color );
```

Answer (score 1):

When a function is defined, the `prototype` property is created automatically:

```
function Animal(age){
    this.age = age;
    console.log("Animal constructor called")
}

Animal.prototype.walk = function(){
     console.log("Animal with age " + this.age + " walked"); 
}
```

Knowing the constructor function, to reference the prototype object is easy: `Animal.prototype`.

From the `prototype` object side, it has a `constructor` property to access the original function: `Animal.prototype.constructor === Animal`. This is useful to determine from an instance what is the original class of it:

```
var lion = new Animal();
console.log(lion.constructor === Animal) // prints "true"
console.log(lion.__proto__.constructor === Animal) // prints "true"
```

---

In case of inheritance, it's necessary manually to setup the constructor:

```
Dog.prototype = new Animal();     
console.log(Dog.prototype.constructor) // prints "function Animal(){}"
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;       // setup manually the constructor to Dog
console.log(Dog.prototype.constructor) // prints "function Dog(){}"
```

in order to verify correctly later it's class:

```
var dog = new Dog("white", 10);

console.log(dog.constructor === Animal)           // prints "false"
console.log(dog.__proto__.constructor === Animal) // prints "false"
console.log(dog.constructor === Dog)              // prints "true"
console.log(dog.__proto__.constructor === Dog)    // prints "true"
```

---

In a few words, the constructor should be fixed if you want to use constructors to verify what class has a specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

After prototype is assigned to another object the constructor of the prototype is lost and needs to be reinitiated (If you are to reference it later) [prototype.constructor tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/constructor)

Answer (score 0):

The following line is what makes `Dog` inherit from `Animal`:

```
 Dog.prototype = new Animal();
```

But, up until this point, the prototype of `Dog` was `Dog` and that meant that the constructor was `Dog`. By swapping out the prototype we now inherit from `Animal`, but the problem now is that when someone comes along to make a new instance of a `Dog`, the constructor from `Animal` will be called because you've swapped out the object that `Dog` inherits from.

So, we just need to correct the constructor part by adding:

```
 Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
```

Now, we're inheriting from `Dog`, but when a new instance of one is made, the constructor from `Dog` will be called, not `Animal`.

And, you'll notice that in the `Dog` constructor function, there is an explicit call to the `Animal` base object constructor:

```
 Animal.call(this, age);
```

So, now when you write this:

```
 var d = new Dog("white", 10);
```

The constructor for `Dog` is called, which calls the constructor for `Animal` and passes the `10` value to that constructor for it to use as the basis for the `age` property. But, it is ensuring with the `this` argument that the new `Dog` is the object that `age` will bind to. Finally, an instance of `Animal` is used as the Prototype object for that new `Dog` instance, so it inherits the properties of `Animal`.